# disable QT highgui output

Tags: qt, opencv

I have compiled OpenCV with QT.
I'm now facing an error which I'm almost certain is related to QT and I would like to output it using the old-fashioned highgui, without the QT interface.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

``` cvNamedWindow( ``myWindow'',  ``CV_WINDOW_NORMAL``   ); ```

will display the windows without any Qt decorations, if you don't want any Qt to be used at all you need to rebuild openCV without Qt

Comment: Ok, I will give it a go
I do generally want QT but I'm using OpenCV through a different interface which I think is conflicting with QT
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021 and OpenCV versions 4x (and maybe less), you can disable Qt Decorations associating flags like below:

```
cv2.namedWindow("main1", cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL | cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
```

You can check all flags [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d90/group__highgui__window__flags.html).