# Segmentation fault when running compiled file from Cmake

Tags: opencv, cmake, point-cloud-library

I am trying to compile a project that depends on PCL and OpenCV.

The CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(pcl_visualizer_viewports)

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
message("this is my message " ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} )
message("this is my message " ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
message("this is my message " ${OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH} )

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (pcl_visualizer_demo pcl_visualizer_demo.cpp readInputFile.cpp readInputFile.h defines.h helper.cpp helper.h Image_Safety.h  Image_Safety.cpp)

target_link_libraries (pcl_visualizer_demo ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

The result is however a segmentation fault and core dumped. I have read through the [Cmake tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/), but I have not found the issue. CMake generates the object files for all:

```
Scanning dependencies of target pcl_visualizer_demo
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcl_visualizer_demo.dir/Image_Safety.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcl_visualizer_demo.dir/helper.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcl_visualizer_demo.dir/image_converter.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcl_visualizer_demo.dir/readInputFile.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcl_visualizer_demo.dir/pcl_visualizer_demo.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable pcl_visualizer_demo
```

Looking at the linking verbose information, the different object files are mentioned and I interpret this as they are linked.

What am I missing?

**update**

Weird so the error occurs in some part of the code using basic opencv functions `cv::waitKey` and `cv::imshow`, it may seem to be an issue with QT [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415673/disable-qt-highgui-output) and [this](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1519).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue.  In the end I had to build PCL without QT (I also found several posts which stated interference, but found no solution)

Comment: Just not a nice solution :/